# Map through an array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, object

I'm going to try and explain this as best I can, bear with me please sorry. I have an array called works that contains multiple objects from a portfolio. I imported the array into my component file and I can just rewrite it over and over but I have multiple elements for each value and my code will be very long. I feel like that isn't very DRY. How I can just put the information into my component once and have it iterate through everything in the array.

Here is a prototype of how I am currently doing it.

```
class PortfolioCard extends React.Component {

 render() {
   return (
  <Card className>
    <CardHeader
      avatar={<Avatar aria-label="Recipe">R</Avatar>}
      title={works[0].title}
      subheader={works[0].name}
    />
    <CardMedia className image={works[0].pic} />

    <CardContent>
      <Typography component="p">
        {works[0].desciption}
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
    <CardActions className disableActionSpacing>
      <IconButton aria-label="Live Site">
        <FavoriteIcon> {works[0].link}
        </FavoriteIcon>
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton aria-label="Github">
        <ShareIcon> {works[0].github}
        </ShareIcon>
      </IconButton>
    </CardActions>
  </Card>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .map to render list of cards something like below in render. Also when you render array of jsx elements don’t forget to set unique key to top jsx element in your case it’s Card

```
 return (
    {works.map((work, index) => (<Card key={"Key-"+index} className>
      <CardHeader
  avatar={<Avatar aria-label="Recipe">R</Avatar>}
  title={work.title}
  subheader={works.name}
/>
<CardMedia className image={work.pic} />

<CardContent>
  <Typography component="p">
    {work.desciption}
  </Typography>
</CardContent>
<CardActions className disableActionSpacing>
  <IconButton aria-label="Live Site">
    <FavoriteIcon> {work.link}
    </FavoriteIcon>
  </IconButton>
  <IconButton aria-label="Github">
    <ShareIcon> {work.github}
    </ShareIcon>
  </IconButton>
</CardActions>
 </Card>))}
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this example help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    works: [
      { name: 'First Work' },
      { name: 'Second Work' },
      { name: 'Third Work' },
    ],
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.works.map((work, i) => {
          return <div key={i}>{work.name}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` to render your array with all the information.

```
class PortfolioCard extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
  <Card className>
  {works.map(({title, name, desciption, pic, link, github}) => ({
    <React.Fragment>
      <CardHeader
        avatar={<Avatar aria-label="Recipe">R</Avatar>}
        title={title}
        subheader={name}
      />
      <CardMedia className image={pic} />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography component="p">
          {desciption}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions className disableActionSpacing>
        <IconButton aria-label="Live Site">
          <FavoriteIcon> {link}
          </FavoriteIcon>
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton aria-label="Github">
          <ShareIcon> {github}
          </ShareIcon>
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
    <React.Fragment>
    }))}
  </Card>
  );
  } 
}
```